# java swing library with layout defined in XML

Tags: java, xml, swing

Is there a swing library that can take its layout from an XMl file?

Comment: Although it uses YAML instead of XML you may want to take a look at JavaBuilders (http://code.google.com/p/javabuilders/). I haven't given a try yet, but it looks pretty interesting from the docs.

Comment: And, I would add, "which one is the best?"

Comment: I built one in 3 hours this last weekend. It only needs 3 lines of java and a small xml document describing the widgets.

Answer (score 6):

[CookSwing](http://cookxml.yuanheng.org/cookswing/)

And [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-user-interface-toolkits) is a large list

Comment: As of August 2017, the latest release is 3.0.2, from 2008.

Answer (score 2):

JFCML: http://jfcml.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The way they mix markup with java code makes me think of spaghetti html + javascript, and that can't be a good thing :)

Answer (score 1):

SWIXML http://www.swixml.org/ is all what u need.

Comment: This website appears to be defunct.

Comment: Latest commit on GitHub was December 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Jakarta [Jelly](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/) And I believe that you can use Spring framework to build UI applications. If you are using Spring you can configure application using the Spring XML.

Comment: Do you mean http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/spring-xml/ ?  "Various XML support classes for Spring Web Services"

Comment: "1.1:  Moved cookswing under cookxml package."